# Combining PHP Registration and Login into one class with multiple functions in one PHP file

Tags: php, function, class, module

I'm trying to combine the registration, activation and login scripts for a php website into a backend script that the front end developer can pass variables from different forms to. **My question is whether this is the appropriate approach to do this. I don't want to have a lot of php files for all the different pieces of the application that I am developing.** So far I have written the following two functions to login, register and activate the user which the front end developer can call:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Karl
 * Date: 26/07/2016
 * Time: 02:25
 */

class users
{
    function register_user($email, $password, $user_name)
    {
        $server_name = "localhost";
        $u_name = "root";
        $db_password = "root";
        $db_name = "betamath_graspe";

        //Email Notification variable
        $from_address="info@slack.com";

        //Registration form
        $msg_reg_user='Username taken. Please choose a different username';
        $msg_reg_email='Email Already registered';
        $msg_reg_active='Activation code has been successfully sent to your Email Address';

        //domain configuration
        $url = ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on") ? "https" : "http");
        $url .= "://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        $url .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);

        // Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli($server_name, $u_name, $db_password, $db_name);
        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }
        //prevent sql injection
        $user_name=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST["user_name"]);
        $password=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST["password"]);
        $email=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST["email"]);

        //check if user exist already
        $query="select * from users where user_name='$user_name'";
        $result=mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die('error');
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result))
        {
            die($msg_reg_user);
        }
        //check if user exist already
        $query="select * from users where email='$email'";
        $result=mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die('error');
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result))
        {
            die($msg_reg_email);

        }

        $active_key = sha1(mt_rand(10000,99999).time().$email);

        if(phpversion() >= 5.5)
        {
            $hashed_password=password_hash($password,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        }
        else
        {
            $hashed_password = crypt($password,'987654321');   //Hash used to suppress PHP notice
        }

        $query="insert into users(username,password,email,active_key) values ('$user_name','$hashed_password','$email','$active_key')";

        if (!mysqli_query($conn,$query))
        {
            die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));

        }

        //send email for the user with password

        $to=$email;
        $subject="Welcome To Graspe";
        $body="Hi ".$user_name.
            "<br /><br /> Thanks for your registration.<br />".
            "Click the below link to activate your account<br /><br />".
            "<a href=\"$url/activate_user_account.php?k=$active_key\"> Activate Account </a><br /><br /> Thanks<br />";


        $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
        $headers .="From:".$from_address . "\r\n";;

        mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);
        echo $msg_reg_active;

    }

    function login_user($username, $password)
    {
        $server_name = "localhost";
        $user_name = "root";
        $db_password = "root";
        $db_name = "betamath_graspe";

        // Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli($server_name, $user_name, $db_password, $db_name);
        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }
        //Message strings
        $msg_pwd_error='Password incorrect';
        $msg_un_error='Username Doesn\'t exist';
        $msg_email_1='User Account not yet activated.';
        $msg_email_2='Click here to resend activation email';

        //domain configuration
        $url = ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on") ? "https" : "http");
        $url .= "://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        $url .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);


        //check if user exist already
        $query="select * from users where username='$username'";
        $result=mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die('error');
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result)) //if exist then check for password
        {
            //Pickup password to compare with encrypted password
            $query="select password,email from users where username='$username'";
            $result=mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die('error');
            $db_field = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            //3.3 $hashed_password=crypt($password,$db_field['password']);

            if(phpversion() >= 5.5)
            {
                if(password_verify($password, $db_field['password']))
                {
                    //once password is verified migrate to password_hash from crypt
                    if(strlen($db_field['password']) < 60)
                    {
                        $hashed_password=password_hash($password,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                        $query = "update users set password='$hashed_password' where username='$username' and email='$db_field[email]'";
                        //echo $query;
                        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die('error updating password hash');
                    }

                    $query="select * from users where username='$username";
                    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die('error');
                    if(mysqli_num_rows($result))
                    {
                        $_SESSION['login'] = true;
                        $_SESSION['username']=$username;
                        echo json_encode( array('result'=>1));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo json_encode( array('result'=>"$msg_email_1 <br /><a href=\"".$url."\\resend_activation_key.php?user=".$username."\">$msg_email_2</a>."));
                        // echo "User Account not yet activated.Check your mail for activation details.";
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    echo json_encode( array('result'=>$msg_pwd_error));
                }

            }
            else
            {
                $hashed_password=crypt($password,$db_field['password']);
                $query="select * from users where username='$username' and password='$hashed_password'";
                $result=mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die('error');
                if (mysqli_num_rows($result))  //if passwords match then check activation status
                {
                    $query="select * from users where username='$username' and password='$hashed_password' and active_status in(1)";
                    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die('error');
                    if(mysqli_num_rows($result))
                    {
                        $_SESSION['login'] = true;
                        $_SESSION['username']=$username;
                        echo json_encode( array('result'=>1));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo json_encode( array('result'=>"$msg_email_1 <br /><a href=\"".$url."\\resend_activation_key.php?user=".$username."\">$msg_email_2</a>."));
                        // echo "User Account not yet activated.Check your mail for activation details.";
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    echo json_encode( array('result'=>$msg_pwd_error));
                    //   echo trim("password incorrect");
                }
            }
        }

        else
        {
            echo json_encode( array('result'=>$msg_un_error));
            //  die("Username Doesn't exist");
            die();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So, what is the actual question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it can be much better than that actually, first of all i don't know if you are using MVC framework or not, but if you don't you have to migrate to one, creating web site the old way is no longer a good practice, but if you don't have time for this, there are better way to do this.

here are some points:

1. have a configuration class so you won't need to write the configuration in each function
2. you are mixing the database queries with the logic you need to separate those you need to create mapper , model and service class, here is a good example for this http://www.slideshare.net/aaronsaray/enterprise-php-mappers-models-and-services
3. one more thing you can consider ORM framework like Doctrine, it will save lots of time